# How to give input to java program and continue with execution using PHP?

Tags: java, php, console, user-input

I want to execute java programs using php code. When i write the below code, the program written in the editor is getting compiled and executed successfully.

```
putenv('path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin');

echo shell_exec("javac $output 2>&1"); // for compiling and creating class file

echo exec("java $check 2>&1"); // for executing generated class file and prints output
```

Note: `$output` and `$check` variables contains required input to compile & run

But, when I try to execute java programs where we need to input some data to contine with the execution, the above code doesn't works. For example, consider the `JavaScannerExample` in the link: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005

To execute the program in the link, I guess I need some interactive console to accept the input and continue with program execution. Please suggest me how to achieve this using php?

**Update:**

@Chris.. Tried `proc_open` command as suggested. See my code below:

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$JAVA_HOME = "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79";
$PATH = "$JAVA_HOME\bin";
putenv("JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME");
putenv("PATH=$PATH");
$result = shell_exec("javac JavaScannerExample.java 2>&1");
if ($result == ""){
$options = ["bypass_shell" => true];
$proc=proc_open("java JavaScannerExample",
  array(
    array("pipe","r"),
    array("pipe","w"),
    array("pipe","w")
  ),
  $pipes,NULL,NULL,$options);
if (is_resource($proc)) {   
   fwrite($pipes[0], 'Mark');
   fwrite($pipes[0], 32);
   fclose($pipes[0]);
   echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); 
   fclose($pipes[1]);
}

}
else{
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaScannerExample
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    // create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //  prompt for the user's name
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

    // get their input as a String
    String username = scanner.next();

    // prompt for their age
    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");

    // get the age as an int
    int age = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println(String.format("%s, your age is %d", username, age));

  }

}
```

**PHP Output**

```
Enter your name: Enter your age:
```

Could you please check and let me know where did I went wrong?

---

**Update2:**

@Chris.. Thanks for your suggestion. It helped me get the output.

Here is the modified php code:

```
putenv('path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin');
$result = shell_exec("javac JavaScannerExample.java 2>&1");
if ($result == ""){
    $options = ["bypass_shell" => true];
    $proc=proc_open("java JavaScannerExample",
            array(
                    array("pipe","r"),
                    array("pipe","w"),
                    array("pipe","w")
            ),
            $pipes,NULL,NULL,$options);
    if (is_resource($proc)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], "Mark\n");
        fwrite($pipes[0], "32\n");
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
    }
}
else{
    echo $result;
}
```

This is the result I am getting.

```
Enter your name: Enter your age: Mark, your age is 32
```

There are multiple problems with this type of result. First I am trying to build an interactive console. So for the above example, the pipes need to work in parallel. However, I am not able to retrieve pipes[1] until I close pipes[0]. Because if I get the value of pipes[1] earlier in the code the program is hanging. In this scenario. First I need to be able to read the input which is "Enter your name:" Then enter input which is "Mark". Next steps are similar I need to get the text "Enter age:" and enter input "32". finally I need to get the final output which is "Mark, your age is 32" and detect the program is finished and then close both the pipes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of exec. It can be used to retrieve a pipe to `stdin` which can be used to provide input to your Java application. The first example on the `proc_open` manual page demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: I have edited the question again.. Used proc_open command as suggested.. Could you kindly check my code and output once and suggest me where I went wrong? Thanks in advance..

Comment: My guess is you are actually entering both values in to the first input. Try adding new lines like this: `fwrite($pipes[0], "Mark\n"); fwrite($pipes[0], "32\n");`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion it worked. But, I have further question. I updated the question with new information. Your support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your update, maybe use `fread` instead of `stream_get_contents`. `fread` should only read what is available, whereas `stream_get_contents` will block until there is guaranteed to be no more readable data in the stream. If you want to get `stdout` before the program has terminated, try something like this.

```
$line_limit = 1024;
echo fread($pipes[1], $line_limit);
fwrite($pipes[0], "Mark\n");
echo fread($pipes[1], $line_limit);
fwrite($pipes[0], "32\n");
echo fread($pipes[1], $line_limit);
fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
```

The only thing to watch out for is if you try and read data before the Java program has finished outputting it then you might not get all the output you expect (possibly nothing at all). If you experience this, I'd add a delay (with [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)) between the writes and the reads.

If you want a truly interactive terminal then you will probably have to spawn a background thread that constantly polls `stdout` for more data, but that's potentially best asked about in another question.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code worked perfectly. But one thing I am struck is how do I distinguish between the question where I need user input and the final output of the program. Basically I need to know when the program final output is printed and the java program is completed? (Because we are currently using the same line of code for question and the final result - fread($pipes[1], $line_limit); )

Comment: @AvinashD You can use `proc_get_status($proc)["running"]` to check whether a process is running or terminated. Be aware though that it can take a fair bit of time for a process to shut down, so you will probably need a delay of some kind. Perhaps a `sleep(1)` before it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It helped me a lot and saved lot of time. :)

Comment: Hello Chris.. Could you kindly check the question in the link and if possible please provide some sample code to proceed. Thanks in advance. [link:] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347269/how-can-i-get-user-input-in-between-php-code-from-client-to-server