# How can I get user input in between php code (from client to server)?

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, ajax

I created php code to run java files and provide result to the user through a web browser. Basically I am trying to create a barebones interactive java web console.  However, this should also work for java files that have user input such as Scanner object.

Here is the sample java file for testing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaScannerExample
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    // create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //  prompt for the user's name
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

    // get their input as a String
    String username = scanner.next();

    // prompt for their age
    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");

    // get the age as an int
    int age = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println(String.format("%s, your age is %d", username, age));

  }

}
```

Currently, I figured how to do this in php. With a predefined set of parameters.

```
<?php

$JAVA_HOME = "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79";
$PATH = "$JAVA_HOME\bin";
putenv("JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME");
putenv("PATH=$PATH");
$result = shell_exec("javac JavaScannerExample.java 2>&1");
$progout = "";

$inputlist = array("32", "Mike");
if ($result == ""){
$options = ["bypass_shell" => true];
$proc=proc_open("java JavaScannerExample",
  array(
    array("pipe","r"),
    array("pipe","w"),
    array("pipe","w")
  ),
  $pipes,NULL,NULL,$options);
if (is_resource($proc)) {   
   $line_limit = 1024;
   $bool = true;
   while ($bool) {
       sleep(1);
       $b = proc_get_status($proc)["running"];  
       if ($b == 1) { // There are still questions
        $inputval = array_pop($inputlist); 
        $q = fread($pipes[1], $line_limit);
        $progout = $progout.$q.' '.$inputval.'<br>';
        fwrite($pipes[0],$inputval."\n");               
       }else{ //Program finished executions.. Get final line
        $bool = false;
        $finaloutput = fread($pipes[1], $line_limit);
        $progout = '<br>'.$progout.$finaloutput;
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
    }//End Else
   }//End While
   echo $progout;
}//End Proc
}//End If
else{
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Here is the result from executing the php code with the sample java file

```
Enter your name: Mike
Enter your age: 32
Mike, your age is 32
```

If you look at the line

```
$inputlist = array("32", "Mike");
```

I am passing the parameters in the hard coded manner.

However I want to be able to get user input through a web browser for the parameters. So instead of the line

```
$inputval = array_pop($inputlist);
```

I need to be able to pause the execution of php code. Then, Get the parameter from the user and store it in $inputval variable and execute the php code. I think we might have to use javascript/jquery using ajax for this. But I am not sure how.

Please help me with this question. Sample code/Pseudo code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen java and javascript tags on the same post, and both of them be correct. Haha!

Comment: You already answered the question by yourself. Take a look at how to handle Ajax requests. Collect that data in your current php file and convert it to your input list.